# How to change app name and icon on flutter desktop windows with build?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I have written a Flutter Desktop app for windows and I want to change the name and icon of app. I change icon from **windows>runner>resources** and I change app name from **windows>runner>main.cpp**. They look changed when I debug. But when I get a build with command `flutter build windows`, the **.exe** coming to my **Release** folder is still with old name and flutter icon. I also want the **.exe** coming from build with new icon and name. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

### For APP Icon

esay way too add  app  icon use flutter plugin [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) after add that code in pub.yam file.

```
dev_dependencies:
 flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.10.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21
web:
 generate: true
 image_path: "path/to/image.png"`
 background_color: "#hexcode"
 theme_color: "#hexcode"
windows:
 generate: true
image_path:"path/to/image.png"
icon_size: 48
```

if you change window,web ya android  application icon  just add your icon path  on  that particular device application.

If you name your configuration file something other than flutter_launcher_icons.yaml or pubspec.yaml you will need to specify the name of the file when running the package.

```
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f <your config file name here>
```

- Second Way
  go your  Project file  in that location windows\runner\resources on that resource  folder youcan see your window application image  change that image with your chossen  image.

---

### Change APP Name

- You can use  plugin [rename: ^2.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) too change  application name
  You can change the bundleId and appName in following folders
- IOS
- Android
- MacOS
- Linux
- Web
- Window
  you just install  that pluging and after you just type command.
  that command chage your application name in all  device application.

> **pub global run rename --appname "Network App"**

but if you  change only particular device app.so  you can type that command.

```
    pub global run rename --bundleId com.example.android.app --target
```

> -t, --target          Set which platforms to target.
> [android, ios, macOS, linux]